# 80s/90s (?) SF book about a space traveler finding a planet, which turns out to be inhabited by humans who left Earth after he did

Tags: story-identification, books, space

This is one of my father's favourite books, he read a library version in the 80s or 90s in the Netherlands and has found it online, so he knows what he remembers is correct/exists. So it's not from after 2000, but could be older dan 80s. I would like to give this book to him as a surprise, so I'm trying to piece together the title/author without having to ask him.

What I remember is that it's about a space traveler who reaches a planet where he finds people that seem human, but he hardly hears/sees them communicate. I believe he was ill at ease and tried to stay out of their way, but is captured in the end. I think the clue was that they actually were humans who colonized the planet after he left Earth. Because his ship was very slow, it took him much longer to get there than the humans who left after him and had much faster ships.

I believe the title of the book was one word and a very normal word (like bug, insect, spider or something else) and the writer's name was pretty normal as well, probably very American.

Comment: Since he likes it so much, it might make him happy if you asked if you could read the e-book. That should get you the title and author at the very least without spoiling the surprise.

Comment: Just to be sure, you tagged this with time-travel, but was there "actual" time travel? From what I read this is just a couple of ships going faster than another one, not going back or forward in time, isn't it?

Comment: yeah,  I wasn't sure about the time trivel either, but from what I gather from my father it initialy has a time travel feeling because the first space traveler doesn't know whats going me on. And it is possible that I don't remember the ending correctely, it could be that the second ships actually time traveled or traveled faster than light. But if the tag makes it to confusion, I wil gladly leave it out

Comment: Don't worry, it's not a big deal :) just trying to see if there was more to the story. If you can think of anything else, don't hesitate to [edit] it in - you might also want to take a look at the [guidelines on story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) to see if that triggers any more memories.

Comment: He problably read it in Dutch, but the title he found was in English

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the edit of the tags! I read the guidelines on story id questions, but onfortunately nothing else comes to mind. I guess it's a little harder, when I'm recounting the memories of my father in stead of my own... But many thanks to the answers so far, I guess this was kind of a hail mary and if it doesn't work thats fine as well (but I would be such a nice suprise if it does work!)

Comment: Oh, I see the title has been edited as well, thanks! I'm not sure it's an 80s/90s book, my father borrowed it from the the library in that timeframe, but it  could be older

Comment: Did perhaps the first traveler go in cryonic suspension (aka coldsleep) and the others at close to light speed (with time dilation)?  Sounds very familiar.

Comment: I might be looking for the same book, but I remember things that are different than some of your details... I don't want to post mine as a question yet, cause I do think mine is a duplicate with and difference in the details being due to human memory and the number of memories involved... And I have spoilers for mine.  Ok, so, story is written from the point of view of a space traveler who wakes from cryosleep to the sounds of alarms and panic, his body hurts from the emergency wake up because the ship skipped some steps to wake him faster, so he knows it's serious. He finds that there was...

Comment: A near collision with something, and that since his ship was so fast, there was damage to things. Many years later when they arrive to explore the barren world, it is fully populated, and they are greeted as heroes from history. The accident was them being passed by a much faster ship that passed too close. Mine was same time frame 80/90s, but I think was a short in a book of shorts. I'd love to find it again!

Comment: @root1657 you have a great deal of detail here, you should actuallly post it as a new question :) link to that one if you think it might be the same;  by asking a new question, you'll bring new attention to both searches :D

Comment: @root1657, the short story you are remembering sounds like Far Centaurus, by A. E. van Vogt, collected in his book Destination: Universe. It features a main character who is sent by slow spaceship to Alpha Centauri. Part way there, he's awakened from cryosleep due to an emergency: there's been a near collision with an unidentified spaceship. The other spaceship is destroyed. Later when he arrives at Alpha Centauri, he find it's already inhabited. Humanity developed fast spaceships and arrived there centuries ago. They greet our main character and treat him as a curious hero from history.

Comment: As for the book the original question is looking for, it doesn't ring a bell to me.